# Ubuntu 16.04 PHP 7 PECL rar don't run

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04, pecl, php-7.0

I want to use the rar extension with PECL on PHP.
I have done the installation: http://php.net/manual/en/rar.installation.php
But I get this error: "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'RarArchive'"
when I run this code:

```
$archive = RarArchive::open($rarfile);
$entries = $archive->getEntries();
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
  $entry->extract('rarfolder');
}
$archive->close();
```

I have solved the problem: 1. php -i | grep extension 2. add to php.ini: "/usr/lib/php/.../rar.so

Comment: Tried using a \? Like so `\RarArchive`

Comment: Yes I have tried \RarArchive! I get the same Error!

Comment: Is your code able to detect the RarArchive class? Can you check that please?

Comment: In which file I have to check it?

Comment: I have solved the problem: 1. php -i | grep extension 2. add to php.ini: "/usr/lib/php/.../rar.so"

Comment: Write your answer in the appropriate field, not in a comment, and mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Copying the comment as answer, hope the OP can mark it as solved:

1. php -i | grep extension
2. add to php.ini: "/usr/lib/php/.../rar.so"

Another solution would be to create a file like:

```
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/rar.ini
```

With the following content:

```
extension=rar.so
```